# HTT, 2.1.1.3, Lurie

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory, model-categories

On [Lurie's Higher Topos Theory, Prop. 2.1.1.3](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf),

> Let $F:C \rightarrow D$ be a functor between categories. Then $C$ is cofibered in groupoids over $D$ if and only if the induced map $N(F):N(C)\rightarrow N(D)$ is a left fibration of simplicial sets.

In line 1 of proof, Lurie states $N(F)$ is an inner fibration - how does this follow from Prop. 1.1.2.2?

We only know that $N(C)$ and $N(D)$ as objects has LLP for inner horns.

Comment: Proposition 1.1.2.2 says nerves of categories have *unique* lifts of inner horns. Try using that fact to prove the following claim: Any map from a quasi-category (i.e., what Lurie calls an $\infty$-category: a simplicial set with LLP with respect to inner horns) to the nerve of a category is an inner fibration.

Comment: @MattFeller, thanks, I will think about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not already resolve this, I believe this is what Matt means. (Correct me if wrong.)

Consider diagram, $n \ge 2$, $0<i<n$, $S$ a quasicategory,
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Lambda^n_i @>h>> S;\\
@VViV @VVfV \\
\Delta^n @>>g> N(C);
\end{CD}
$$
 $g$ is the unique lift of the morphism $i$ with respect to $fh$. (nerves of category have unique lifts)

Given any lift $k:\Delta^n \rightarrow S$ of upper left diagram: $ki=h$ we have $$fki=fh=gi$$ So $fk=g$ from uniqueness.   Thus, $f$ is an inner fibration.

Comment: Yep! That’s what I had in mind.